# a function for a football league program

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FootballTeam.h"
using namespace std;

CFootballTeam league[10];
int numTeams = 0;

int ShowMenu(void);
void DoInitalize();
void DoDisplayLeague(void);
void DoEnterMatchResult(void);
void DoDeductPoints(void);
void DoBestDefence(void);
void DoRelegationZone(void);
void DoAddTeamToList(void);
void DoQuit(void);

bool quitFlag = false;
int main()
{
    int option;
    do
    {
        option = ShowMenu();
        switch (option)
        {
        case 0:
            DoInitalize();
            break;
        case 1:
            DoDisplayLeague();
            break;
        case 2:
            DoEnterMatchResult();
            break;
        case 3:
            DoDeductPoints();
            break;
        case 4:
            DoBestDefence();
            break;
        case 5:
            DoRelegationZone();
            break;
        case 6:
            DoAddTeamToList();
            break;
        case 7:
            DoQuit();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "invalid option\n";
        }
    } while (!quitFlag);

    if (numTeams == 0)
        return 0;

    ofstream outfile("leagueInfo.dat");
    outfile << numTeams << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTeams; i++)
    {
        outfile << league[i].GetName() << "  "
            /*<< league[i].GetGamesPlayed() << "  "
            << league[i].GetGoalsFor() << "  "
            << league[i].GetGoalsAgainst << "  "
            << league[i].GetPoints*/ << endl;
    }

    outfile.close();
    return 0;


    return 0;
}
int ShowMenu(void)
{
    int option;
    cout << "\t0.       Initialize League Table\n";
    cout << "\t1.       Display League Table\n";
    cout << "\t2.       Enter a Match Result\n";
    cout << "\t3.       Deduct Points\n";
    cout << "\t4.       Best Defence\n";
    cout << "\t5.       Relegation Zone\n";
    cout << "\t6.       Add Team to List\n";
    cout << "t7.        Quit\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t     Enter Option ? ";
    cin >> option;
    return option;
}


void DoInitalize()
{
    char response;
    do
    {
        string name;
        cout << "Enter a name:";
        cin >> name;
        CFootballTeam s(name);
        league[numTeams] = s;
        numTeams++;
        cout << "More (Y/N) ? ";
        cin >> response;
    } while (response == 'y' || response == 'Y');
}
```

this id the code I have so far and it doesn't seem right to me  and this is what its meant to do and I don't think iv doe it right.. any help be appreciated

DoInitialize  should initialise a league table.
callback for option 0 //Scan the collection .... 
allow user to enter a team name 
instantiate an object 
copy the object into the collection 
can someone please help me with this ??

Comment: SO is not a code writing service - you need to ask a more specific question than that. And also explain what the problem is with the code you have written

Comment: I'm new to this site.. sorry... once I run this in console it just keeps running have to x out of it to stop

Comment: It will just keep running because you never set quitFlag to true anywhere, right? If I make a function DoQuit() that sets quitFlag to true, the program exits as expected.